# mysql join not use index for 'between' operator

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, between

So basically I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `cdIPAddressToLocation` (
  `IPADDR_FROM` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Low end of the IP Address block',
  `IPADDR_TO` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'High end of the IP Address block',
  `IPLOCID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The Location ID for the IP Address range',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`IPADDR_TO`),
  KEY `Index_2` USING BTREE (`IPLOCID`),
  KEY `Index_3` USING BTREE (`IPADDR_FROM`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `cdIPLocation` (
  `IPLOCID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `Country` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `Region` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `City` varchar(90) default NULL,
  `PostalCode` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `Latitude` float NOT NULL,
  `Longitude` float NOT NULL,
  `MetroCode` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `AreaCode` varchar(4) default NULL,
  `State` varchar(45) default NULL,
  `Continent` varchar(10) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`IPLOCID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=218611 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE 'data'{
 'IP' varchar(50)
 'SCORE' int
}
```

My task is to join these three tables and find the location data  for given IP address.
My query is as follows:

```
select 
    t.ip,
    l.Country,
    l.State,
    l.City,
    l.PostalCode,
    l.Latitude,
    l.Longitude,
    t.score
from
    (select 
        ip, inet_aton(ip) ipv, score
    from
        data
    order by score desc
    limit 5) t
        join
    cdIPAddressToLocation a ON t.ipv between a.IPADDR_FROM and a.IPADDR_TO
        join
    cdIPLocation l ON l.IPLOCID = a.IPLOCID
```

While this query works, it's very very slow, it took about 100 seconds to return the result on my dev box.

I'm using mysql 5.1, the cdIPAddressToLocation has 5.9 million rows and cdIPLocation table has about 0.3 million rows.

When I check the execution plan, I found it's not using any index in the table 'cdIPAddressToLocation', so for each row in the 'data' table it would do a full table scan against table 'cdIPAddressToLocation'.
It is very weird to me. I mean since there are already two indexes in table 'cdIPAddressToLocation' on columns 'IPADDR_FROM' and 'IPADDR_TO', the execution plan should exploit the index to improve the performance, but why it didn't use them.

Or was there something wrong with my query?

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll find that it won't use the indexes if you switch to using `t.ipv >= a.IPADDR_FROM AND t.ipv <= a.IPADDR_TO`. Ran in the same thing myself, and couldn't figure it out. ended up punting and splitting the ip table into multiple separate ones and sending the query to the appropriate range based on netmasks, since it was just a one-time run.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a composite index on the columns cdIPAddressToLocation.IPADDR_FROM and cdIPAddressToLocation.IPADDR_TO?

[Multiple-Column Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)